# Reverse for 'post_text' not found. 'post_text' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my project for a course and I'm totally stuck right now. I'm creating a website to profenity, there after logging there after pages are not rendering properly. I've followed the examples in my lessons and checked the code a hundred times but obviously there is something I'm missing

i'm having some issues on revercenotFound
when i logging there i getting this error everthing working properly before when i pushed code into server i getting this error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /user_dashboard
Reverse for 'post_text' not found. 'post_text' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_dashboard
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post_text' not found. 'post_text' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 694, 
in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/eunagi/Project/image_processing',
'/usr/local/bin',
'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 27 Jul 2021 10:38:54 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template /home/eunagi/Project/image_processing/templates/user_base.html, error at line 33

Reverse for 'post_text' not found. 'post_text' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
23                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
24                      </button>
25                  </div>
26  
27                  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-pad">
28                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynav" id="nav">
29                          <li class="active"><a href="{% url 
                            'user_dashboard'%}">Dashboard</a></li>
30                          <li class="">
31                              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Post 
                           Content<span class="caret"></span></a>
32                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
33                                  <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_text'%}">Post Text</a> 
                                    </li>
34                                  <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_image'%}">Post 
                                    Image</a></li>
35                                  <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_video'%}">Post 
                                     Video</a></li>
36                                  <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_audio'%}">Post 
                                    Audio</a></li>
37                              </ul>
38                          </li>
39                          <li class=""><a href="{% url 'user_my_content'%}">My Content</a> 
                            </li>
40                      </ul>
41                      <div class="nav-label">
42                          <ul typeof="none" class="pull-right">
43
```

here is my url.py

this is my url setting that written in like this.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
  path('home',views.home,name='home'),
  path('register',views.register,name='register'),
  path('',views.login1,name='login1'),
  path('login1',views.login1,name='login1'),
  path('admin_login',views.admin_login,name='admin_login'),
  path('change_password',views.change_password,name='change_password'),

  path('contact_us',views.contact_us,name='contact_us'),
  path('help',views.help,name='help'),
  path('privacy_policy',views.privacy_policy,name='privacy_policy'),
  path('terms_condition',views.terms_condition,name='terms_condition'),
  path('about_us',views.about_us,name='about_us'),
  path('test',views.test,name='test'),
  path('logout_user',views.logout_user,name='logout_user'),
  path('logout_admin',views.logout_admin,name='logout_admin'),
  path('user_dashboard',views.user_dashboard,name='user_dashboard'),
  path('moderator_dashboard',views.moderator_dashboard,name='moderator_dashboard'),
  path('create_user',views.create_user,name='create_user'),

  path('user_register',views.user_register,name='user_register'),
  path('add_project_code',views.add_project_code,name='add_project_code'),
  path('delete_project_code/<int:pk>',views.delete_project_code,name='delete_project_code'),
  path('edit_project_code/<int:pk>',views.edit_project_code,name='edit_project_code'),
  path('create_project',views.create_project,name='create_project'),
  path('edit_user/<int:pk>',views.edit_user,name='edit_user'),
  path('user_assignment',views.user_assignment,name='user_assignment'),
  path('profanity_dic',views.profanity_dic,name='profanity_dic'),

  path('add_profanity_word',views.add_profanity_word,name='add_profanity_word'),



  path('edit_profanity_word/<int:pk>',views.edit_profanity_word,name='edit_profanity_word'),

  path('user_my_content',views.user_my_content,name='user_my_content'),
  path('admin_moderate',views.admin_moderate,name='admin_moderate'), 


  path('post_text', views.post_text, name='post_text'),
  path('post_image', views.post_image, name='post_image'),
  path('post_audio', views.post_audio, name='post_audio'),
  path('post_video', views.post_video, name='post_video'), 

 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

this is my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='admin_login')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'error': "Username Already Exists"})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                        first_name=request.POST.get('firstname'),
                                        last_name=request.POST.get('lastname'), email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                        password=request.POST.get('password'))
        mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number')
        country_name = request.POST.get('country_name')

        newextenduser = extendeduser(mobile_number=mobile_number, country_name=country_name, user=user)
        newextenduser.save()
        auth.login(request, user)
        print("User saved")
        return render(request, 'login.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'register.html')


def login1(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        user.is_active = True
        auth.login(request, user)
        print("Sucessfully Login")
        return redirect('user_dashboard')
    else:
        print("Fail")
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials.')
        return redirect('login1')

else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')


def admin_login(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        user1 = extendeduser.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
        if user1 is not None:

            if user1.user_type == 'Admin':
                user1.is_active = True
                auth.login(request, user)
                print("Sucessfully Login")
                return redirect('home')
            elif user1.user_type == 'Moderator':
                user1.is_active = True
                auth.login(request, user)
                print("Sucessfully Login 2")
                return redirect('moderator_dashboard')

            else:
                messages.info(request, 'You are Not Admin.')
                return redirect('/admin_login')

    else:
        print("Fail")
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials.')
        return redirect('/admin_login')

else:
    return render(request, 'admin_login.html')


def change_password(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    current = request.POST.get('currentpass')
    new_pas = request.POST.get('password1')

    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    un = user.username
    check = user.check_password(current)
    if check == True:
        user.set_password(new_pas)
        user.save()
        messages.info(request, 'Password Changed Successfully!!!.')

        user = User.objects.get(username=un)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/change_password')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Incorrect Current Password.')
        return redirect('/change_password')

return render(request, 'change-password.html')


def contact_us(request):
    return render(request, 'contact-us.html')


def help(request):
    return render(request, 'help.html')


def privacy_policy(request):
    return render(request, 'privacy-policy.html')


def terms_condition(request):
    return render(request, 'terms-and-condition.html')


def about_us(request):
     return render(request, 'about-us.html')


def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login1')


def logout_admin(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('admin_login')


def create_user(request):
    user2 = extendeduser.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'create_user.html', {'user2': user2})


def user_register(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        return render(request, 'user_register.html', {'error': "Username Already Exists"})
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get('username'),
                                        first_name=request.POST.get('firstname'),
                                        last_name=request.POST.get('lastname'), email=request.POST.get('email'),
                                        password=request.POST.get('password'))
        user_type = request.POST.get('user_type')
        newextenduser = extendeduser(user_type=user_type, user=user)
        newextenduser.save()
        messages.info(request, 'User Created Successfully!!!.')
        return render(request, 'user_register.html')
else:

    return render(request, 'user_register.html')


def edit_user(request, pk):
 user2 = extendeduser.objects.get(user_id=pk)

  if request.method == 'POST':

    extendeduser.objects.filter(user_id=pk).update(user_type=request.POST.get('user_type'),
                                                   is_active=request.POST.get('is_active'))

    get_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=pk)

    get_user.first_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
    get_user.last_name = request.POST.get('lastname')

    get_user.save()

    print("User saved")
    return redirect('create_user')

else:

    return render(request, 'edit_user.html', {'user2': user2})


def user_dashboard(request):
   return render(request, 'user_home.html')


def moderator_dashboard(request):
   return render(request, 'moderator_dashboard.html')


def add_project_code(request):
  items = Project_Code.objects.all()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    project_name = request.POST.get('project_name')
    project_code = Project_Code(project_name=project_name)
    project_code.save()
    print("Saved project")
    return redirect('create_project')
else:

    return render(request, 'add_project_code.html', {'items': items})


def edit_project_code(request, pk):
  project = Project_Code.objects.get(project_id=pk)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    Project_Code.objects.filter(project_id=pk).update(project_name=request.POST.get('project_name'))
    return redirect('create_project')

else:

    return render(request, 'edit_project_code.html', {'project': project})


def create_project(request):
   project = Project_Code.objects.all()

   return render(request, 'create_project.html', {'project': project})


def delete_project_code(request, pk):
    Project_Code.objects.filter(project_id=pk).delete()
    return redirect('create_project')


def user_assignment(request):
    project = Project_Code.objects.all()
    rolesuser = extendeduser.objects.all()

   return render(request, 'user_assignment.html', {'project': project, 'rolesuser': rolesuser})


def profanity_dic(request):
  dic = ProfanityDictionary.objects.all()
  dic2 = Project_Code.objects.all()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    search = request.POST.get('letter')
    code = request.POST.get('code')
    if search != '' and code == '0':

        dic = ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(dictonary_word__icontains=search)
    elif search == request.POST.get('letter') and code == request.POST.get('code') or code != 0:
        dic = ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(Q(dictonary_word__icontains=search) & Q(project_code_id=code))

    elif search == '':
        search = None
        dic = ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(Q(project_code_id=code))
    elif search == request.POST.get('letter'):
        dic = ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(Q(dictonary_word__icontains=search) | Q(project_code_id=code))
    
    return render(request, 'profanity_dic.html', {'dic': dic})

else:

    return render(request, 'profanity_dic.html', {'dic': dic, 'dic2': dic2})


def add_profanity_word(request):
  project_code = Project_Code.objects.all()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    word = request.POST.get('word')
    project_code = request.POST.get('project_code')
    severity = request.POST.get('severity')

    profanity = ProfanityDictionary(dictonary_word=word, severity=severity, project_code_id=project_code)
    profanity.save()
    print("Data saved")
    return redirect('profanity_dic')

else:

    return render(request, 'add_profanity_word.html', {'project_code': project_code})


def delete_profanity_word(request, pk):
   ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(dictonary_id=pk).delete()
   return redirect('profanity_dic')


def edit_profanity_word(request, pk):
  profanity_word = ProfanityDictionary.objects.get(dictonary_id=pk)
  project_code = Project_Code.objects.all()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    word = request.POST.get('word')
    project_name = request.POST.get('project_name')
    severity = request.POST.get('severity')
    print(project_name)

    ProfanityDictionary.objects.filter(dictonary_id=pk).update(dictonary_word=word, severity=severity,
                                                               project_code_id=project_name)
    return redirect('profanity_dic')


else:

    return render(request, 'edit_profanity_word.html',
                  {'profanity_word': profanity_word, 'project_code': project_code})


def post_text(request):
    return render(request, 'post_text.html')


def post_image(request):
    return render(request, 'post_image.html')


def post_audio(request):
    return render(request, 'post_audio.html')


def post_video(request):
    return render(request, 'post_video.html')


def user_my_content(request):
    return render(request, 'user_my_content.html')
```

user_base.html

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-pad">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mynav" id="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'user_dashboard'%}">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Post Content<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_text'%}">Post Text</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_image'%}">Post Image</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_video'%}">Post Video</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'post_audio'%}">Post Audio</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="{% url 'user_my_content'%}">My Content</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="nav-label">
                    <ul typeof="none" class="pull-right">


                        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="GuBDylIHZwe7gdgD1yljilr6G--6MgoPKD-yCSkQctRPSdIOOYAg_aqv2eqCu59mxCorJAYin00TTh8mCek5l54j-jPtpxGDRnRqEBvugqs1">
                        <li class="">
                            <label class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Welcome 
                                <span>
                                      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                        {{user.username}}
                    
                                      {% endif %}
                                    </span> 
                                <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </label>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-button logdrop logoff">
                                <li class=""><a href="{% url 'logout_user' %}">Log Off</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: does does your views.py look like?

Comment: Do you have a view named post_text in your views.py file?

Comment: yes i have i updated my post plz check

Comment: @AshishNautiyal plz check my updated question

Comment: Does your ```user_home.html``` contain any anchor tags to ```post_text``` ? Please post your ```user_home.html``` code as well @MahiC

Comment: @Ram no not any

Comment: What you have posted is ```user_base.html``` ? Are ```user_home.html``` and ```user_base.html``` same ?

Comment: @Ram no its diffrent